# Read custom metadata from onnx model in C#

Tags: c#, onnx, onnxruntime

When creating an InferenceSession in my C# application I want to access the custom metadata from the .onnx model.

I populate the model with metadata in python:

```
model = onnxmltools.load_model("../models/model.onnx")

meta = model.metadata_props.add()
meta.key = "version"
meta.value = "0.0.1"
print(model.metadata_props[0])
onnxmltools.utils.save_model(model, "../models/model_1.onnx")
```

When trying to load the model in C#:

```
private InferenceSession _session;
_session = new InferenceSession(_modelPath, new SessionOptions());
// I can access the model input-/ouput-metadata e.g. input dimensions:
var dims = _session.InputMetadata["input_1"].Dimensions;
// my custom metadata key-value-pair is not there
```

I want to display the model version, model type and other properties in the application. Is there another way to do this?

I am using the Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime v1.4.0 NuGet package in the C# application.
The version of the onnxmltools in python is 1.6.1

Happy about any help!

Cheers

Daniel

Comment: I also opened a feature request at [onnxruntime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/4568).

Comment: Would this help you utilize Onnx in c# : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437235/cannot-get-correct-predictions-from-onnx-model-from-customvision/70439153#70439153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for opening an issue in Github as well to track. I have it on my list. I ll try and get this into the next release.