# Cannot get correct predictions from ONNX model from Customvision

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, microsoft-custom-vision, onnxruntime

I am evaluating customvision.ai for training image classification model and then downloading that model as an onnx file that would be consumed within a .Net Windows forms app.

I created a new project, uploaded few images, tagged them and was able to fetch predictions from the model within Customvision.ai .The model accuracy was acceptable. CustomVision allows you to download a model as an ONNX file which can be deployed within a cross platform application. In my case I plan to deploy and consume the model within a Windows forms application.

When I download the model as onnx, I receive a zip file that contains the .onnx file and few others.

One of the file is Metadata_properties.json, and it has the following contents:

```
{
    "CustomVision.Metadata.AdditionalModelInfo": "",
    "CustomVision.Metadata.Version": "1.2",
    "CustomVision.Postprocess.Method": "ClassificationMultiClass",
    "CustomVision.Postprocess.Yolo.Biases": "[]",
    "CustomVision.Postprocess.Yolo.NmsThreshold": "0.0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.CropHeight": "0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.CropMethod": "FullImageShorterSide",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.CropWidth": "0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.MaxDimension": "0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.MaxScale": "0.0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.MinDimension": "0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.MinScale": "0.0",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.NormalizeMean": "[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.NormalizeStd": "[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.ResizeMethod": "Stretch",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.TargetHeight": "300",
    "CustomVision.Preprocess.TargetWidth": "300",
    "Image.BitmapPixelFormat": "Rgb8",
    "Image.ColorSpaceGamma": "SRGB",
    "Image.NominalPixelRange": "Normalized_0_1"
}
```

What I understand from this file is that the eventual Tensor that would be provided to the model for inference would need to be stretch resized to 300x300, Normalized between 0 and 1, Mean set to zero and stdev set to 1. In order to consume this model within my code, here is what I put together from various online sources:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
//using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Tensors;
using Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime;
using System.IO;

namespace TestONNXRunner
{
   

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RunModel();
        }

        public void RunModel()
        {
            // Read paths
            string modelFilePath = @"C:\ImageMLProjects\MarbleImagesDataset\OnnxModel\onnxdataset\model.onnx";
            var LabelsDict = GetLabelMap(@"C:\ImageMLProjects\MarbleImagesDataset\OnnxModel\onnxdataset\labels.txt");


            string imageFilePath = @"";
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Title = "Browse Image Files",

                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,

                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true,

                ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                ShowReadOnly = true
            };

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imageFilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                // Read image
                using Image<Rgb24> image = Image.Load<Rgb24>(imageFilePath);

                // Resize image
                image.Mutate(x =>
                {
                    x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                    {
                        Size = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Size(300, 300),
                        Mode = ResizeMode.Stretch
                    });
                });

                // Preprocess image
                Tensor<float> input = new DenseTensor<float>(new[] { 1, 3, image.Height, image.Width });
                var mean = new[] { 0f, 0f, 0f };
                var stddev = new[] { 1f, 1f, 1f };
                for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
                {
                    Span<Rgb24> pixelSpan = image.GetPixelRowSpan(y);
                    for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                    {
                        input[0, 0, x, y] = ((pixelSpan[x].R / 255f) - mean[0]) / stddev[0];
                        input[0, 1, x, y] = ((pixelSpan[x].G / 255f) - mean[1]) / stddev[1];
                        input[0, 2, x, y] = ((pixelSpan[x].B / 255f) - mean[2]) / stddev[2];
                    }
                }

                // Setup inputs
                var inputs = new List<NamedOnnxValue>
                {
                    NamedOnnxValue.CreateFromTensor("data", input)
                };

                // Run inference
                //int gpuDeviceId = 0; // The GPU device ID to execute on
                //var session = new InferenceSession("model.onnx", SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCudaProvider(gpuDeviceId));
                using var session = new InferenceSession(modelFilePath);
                using IDisposableReadOnlyCollection<DisposableNamedOnnxValue> results = session.Run(inputs);

                // Postprocess to get softmax vector
                IEnumerable<float> output = results.First().AsEnumerable<float>();
                float sum = output.Sum(x => (float)Math.Exp(x));
                IEnumerable<float> softmax = output.Select(x => (float)Math.Exp(x) / sum);

                // Extract top 10 predicted classes
                IEnumerable<Prediction> top10 = softmax.Select((x, i) => new Prediction { Label = LabelsDict[i], Confidence = x })
                                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Confidence)
                                   .Take(10);

                // Print results to console
                Console.WriteLine("Top 10 predictions for ResNet50 v2...");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
                foreach (var t in top10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Label: {t.Label}, Confidence: {t.Confidence}");
                }
            }
        }


        public Dictionary<int, string> GetLabelMap(string LabelMapFile)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> labelsDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            if(File.Exists(LabelMapFile))
            {
                string data = File.ReadAllText(LabelMapFile);

                string[] labels = data.Split('\n');
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var label in labels)
                {
                    labelsDict.Add(i, label);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return labelsDict;
        }
        internal class Prediction
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public float Confidence { get; set; }
        }


      
    }
}
```

**Now what is the problem?**

I see no errors, Irrespective of what image I use for inference, I just get the same result.

**Questions**

1. Should I structure the tensor differently? I am not sure if this is something to do with the way the Tensor is structured.
2. The last updates to Customvision pages on Github was several years ago, Is CustomVision recommended for production usage in 2021? Should I be looking out for something else? The idea is to be able to build/train high quality image classification models with a low/zero code approach and then deploy the model onto on premise computers for use in low latency applications.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to utilize the Onnx model exported from Azure Custom Vision to obtain scores from an Image classification Model. I use ML.NET and OnnxRuntime in order to do so. The code works perfectly and the sample below can be used to run mass inferencing of images stored in a folder using a .Net Console Application and a .ONNX model exported from CustomVision.

```
public class OnnxModelScorer
{

public class ImageInputData
{
    [ImageType(300, 300)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}

public class ImagePrediction
{
        
    [ColumnName("model_output")]
    public float[] PredictedLabels;
}

PredictionEngine<ImageInputData, ImagePrediction> predictionEngine;
ModelMetadataPropertiesClass modelprops;
Dictionary<int, string> ModelLabels = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public void SetupPredictionEngine(string modelFolderPath, out string errors)
{
    errors = "";
    predictionEngine = null;
    try
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        modelprops = LoadProperties(modelFolderPath + "metadata_properties.json", out string error);

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
                        .ResizeImages("image", modelprops.CustomVisionPreprocessTargetWidth, modelprops.CustomVisionPreprocessTargetHeight, nameof(ImageInputData.Image), ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill)
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels("data", "image"))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel("model_output", "data", modelFolderPath + @"model.onnx"));

        var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<ImageInputData>());
        var model = pipeline.Fit(data);

        predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ImageInputData, ImagePrediction>(model);

        string[] labels = File.ReadAllText(modelFolderPath + @"labels.txt").Split('\n');

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            ModelLabels.Add(i, label);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errors = "Model Loading Failed: " + ex.ToString();
    }
        
}

public PredictionResultClass GetModelPrediction(Bitmap sample, out string error)
{
    PredictionResultClass pr = new PredictionResultClass();
    error = "";
    if (predictionEngine != null)
    {
        var input = new ImageInputData { Image = sample };

        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(input);
        Dictionary<int, PredictionResultClass> predictionResults = new Dictionary<int, PredictionResultClass>();
        int indexofMaxProb = -1;
        float maxProbability = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < prediction.PredictedLabels.Count(); i++)
        {
            predictionResults.Add(i,new PredictionResultClass() { Label = ModelLabels[i], probability = prediction.PredictedLabels[i] });

            if(prediction.PredictedLabels[i]>maxProbability)
            {
                maxProbability = prediction.PredictedLabels[i];
                indexofMaxProb = i;
            }
        }

        pr = predictionResults[indexofMaxProb];

    }
    else error = "Prediction Engine Not initialized";

    return pr;
}
public class PredictionResultClass
{
    public string Label = "";
    public float probability = 0;
}

public void ModelMassTest(string samplesfolder)
{
        
    string[] inputfiles = Directory.GetFiles(samplesfolder);
    List<double> analysistimes = new List<double>();
    foreach (var fl in inputfiles)
    {

        //Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte> Img = new Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>(fl);
        // Img.ROI = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rectangle>("\"450, 288, 420, 1478\"");
        // string savePath = @"C:\ImageMLProjects\Tresseme200Ml Soiling Experiment\Tresseme200MlImages\ROIApplied\Bad\" + Path.GetFileName(fl);
        // Img.Save(savePath);

        //Bitmap bitmap = Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension.ToBitmap(Img); // your source of a bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fl);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var res =  GetModelPrediction(bitmap, out string error);

        sw.Stop();
        PrintResultsonConsole(res, Path.GetFileName(fl));




        Console.WriteLine($"Analysis Time(ms): {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        analysistimes.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    }

    if(analysistimes.Count()>0)
        Console.WriteLine($"Average Analysis Time(ms): {analysistimes.Average()}");
}


public static ModelMetadataPropertiesClass LoadProperties(string MetadatePropertiesFilepath, out string error)
{
    string propertiesText = File.ReadAllText(MetadatePropertiesFilepath);
    error = "";
    ModelMetadataPropertiesClass mtp = new ModelMetadataPropertiesClass();

    try
    {
        mtp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelMetadataPropertiesClass>(propertiesText);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.ToString();
        mtp = null;
    }

    return mtp;
}
public class ModelMetadataPropertiesClass
{
    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Metadata.AdditionalModelInfo")]
    public string CustomVisionMetadataAdditionalModelInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Metadata.Version")]
    public string CustomVisionMetadataVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Postprocess.Method")]
    public string CustomVisionPostprocessMethod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Postprocess.Yolo.Biases")]
    public string CustomVisionPostprocessYoloBiases { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Postprocess.Yolo.NmsThreshold")]
    public string CustomVisionPostprocessYoloNmsThreshold { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.CropHeight")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessCropHeight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.CropMethod")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessCropMethod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.CropWidth")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessCropWidth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.MaxDimension")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessMaxDimension { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.MaxScale")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessMaxScale { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.MinDimension")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessMinDimension { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.MinScale")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessMinScale { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.NormalizeMean")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessNormalizeMean { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.NormalizeStd")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessNormalizeStd { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.ResizeMethod")]
    public string CustomVisionPreprocessResizeMethod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.TargetHeight")]
    public int CustomVisionPreprocessTargetHeight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomVision.Preprocess.TargetWidth")]
    public int CustomVisionPreprocessTargetWidth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Image.BitmapPixelFormat")]
    public string ImageBitmapPixelFormat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Image.ColorSpaceGamma")]
    public string ImageColorSpaceGamma { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Image.NominalPixelRange")]
    public string ImageNominalPixelRange { get; set; }
}


public static void PrintResultsonConsole( PredictionResultClass pr,string  filePath)
{
    var defaultForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
    var labelColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    var probColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    var exactLabel = ConsoleColor.Green;
    var failLabel = ConsoleColor.Red;

    Console.Write("ImagePath: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = labelColor;
    Console.Write($"{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;

    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;
    Console.Write(" predicted as ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = exactLabel;
    Console.Write($"{pr.Label}");

    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;
    Console.Write(" with probability ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = probColor;
    Console.Write(pr.probability);
    Console.ForegroundColor = defaultForeground;
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
}
```

To initialize the prediction engine and obtain an score using an onnx model, I use the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{



var onnxModelScorer = new OnnxModelScorer();

onnxModelScorer.SetupPredictionEngine(@"C:\ModelFileFolder\OnnxModel\",out string error);

// Download the onnx model zip file from CustomVision and extract all in same folder( the labels, metadata and onnx files are utilized to initialize the prediction engine)

onnxModelScorer.ModelMassTest(@"C:\SampleImagesFolder\");
//

        
ConsoleHelpers.ConsolePressAnyKey();
}
```

FYI, It it matters, the average inferencing time was around 40ms, Using the Onnx DirectML or GPU packages did not help improve this.

NB: This answer is a mix of various samples on the onnxruntime Github repo, Stackoverflow and internet sources on ML.NET